# What makes a problem more fundamental than another?

Tags: algorithm, definition

Is there any formal definition for what makes a problem more fundamental than another? Otherwise, what would be an acceptable informal definition?

An example of a problem that is more fundamental than another would be sorting vs font rendering.

Comment: How is font rendering reducibe to sorting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original question is a valid one, and does not have to assume/consider complexity and reducibility as @slebetman suggested. (Thus making the question more fundamental :)

If we attempt a formal definition, we could have this one: Problem P1 is more fundamental than problem P2, if a solution to P1 affects the outcome of a **wider set of other  problems**. This likely implies that P1 will affect problems in different domains of computer science - and possibly beyond.

In practical terms, I would correct again @slebetman. Instead of "if something uses or challenges an assumption then it is less fundamental than that assumption", I would say **"if a problem uses or challenges an assumption then it is less fundamental than the same problem without the assumption"**. I.e. sorting of Objects is more fundamental than sorting of Integers; or, font rendering on a printer is less fundamental than font rendering on any device.

Answer (score 3):

When many problems can be solved using one algorithm, for instance. This is the case for any optimal algorithm for sorting. BTW, perhaps you're mixing problems and algorithms? There is a formal definition of one problem being reducible to another. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_(complexity)

Comment: There is no confusion here between problems and algorithm. In computing there are many fundamental problems which are NOT algorithms for example P!=NP and the halting problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question right.

When you can solve the same problem by applying many algorithms, the algorithm which proves its lightweight on both of memory and CPU is considered more fundamental. And I can think of another thing which is, a fundamental algorithm will not use other algorithms, otherwise it would be a complex one.

Comment: How 'lightweight' something is has nothing to do with fundamentalness since the question `is the brute-force approach the only way to solve this and if so can the brute-force approach be speeded up?` is one of THE most fundamental problems in computing (up there with the halting problem). The formal name for the problem is: `P != NP or P = NP`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem or solution that has *more applications* is *more fundamental*.

(Sorting has many appications,  P!=NP too has many applications (or implications), rendeering only has a few applications.)

Answer (score 0):

Inf is right when he hinted at complexity and reducibility but not just of what is involved/included in an algorithm's implementation. It's the assumptions you make.

All pieces of code are written with assumptions about the world in which it operates. Those assumptions are more fundamental than the code written with those assumptions. In short, I would say: **if something uses or challenges an assumption then it is less fundamental than that assumption**.

Lets take an example: sorting. The problem of sorting is that when done the naive way the time it takes to sort grows very quickly. In technical terms, the problem of sorting tends towards being NP complete. So sorting algorithms are developed with the aim of avoiding being NP complete. But is NP complete always slow? That's a problem unto itself and the problem is called P!=NP which so far has not been proven either true or false. So P!=NP is more fundamental than sorting.

But even P!=NP makes some assumptions. It assumes that NP complete problems can always be run to completion even if it takes a long time to complete. In other words, the big-O notation for an NP complete problem is never infinite. This begs the question are all problems guaranteed to have a point of completion? The answer to that is no, not all problems have a guaranteed point of completion, the most trivial of which is the infinite loop: `while (1) {print "still running!"}`. So can we detect all cases of programs running infinitely? No, and the proof of that is the halting problem. Hence the halting problem is more fundamental than P!=NP.

But even the halting problem makes assumptions. We assume that we are running all our programs on a particular kind of CPU. Can we treat all CPUs as equivalent? Is there a CPU out there that can be built to solve the halting problem? Well, the answer is as long as a CPU is Turing complete, they are equivalent with other CPUs that are Turing complete. Turing completeness is therefore a more fundamental problem than the halting problem.

We can go on and on and question our assumptions like: are all kinds of signals equivalent? Is it possible that a fluidic or mechanical computer be fundamentally different than an electronic computer? And it will lead us to things like Shannon's information theory and Boolean algebra etc and each assumption that we uncover are more fundamental than the one above it.

Comment: "In technical terms, the problem of sorting tends towards being NP complete. " - er, what? Not only is sorting not NP complete, but I can't imagine anyone seriously considering it might be.

Comment: @Nick: The worst possible implementation of sorting is one that requires you to find the smallest possible number in the first round, then the second smallest number in the second round then third smallest etc.. which is NP complete. This is how humans naturally sort things in the physical world and is one of the algorithms likely to be implemented by a newbie when first exposed to this problem.

Comment: @slebetman said: if something uses or challenges an assumption then it is less fundamental than that assumption. LordCover said: a fundamental algorithm will not use other algorithms, otherwise it would be a complex one. The same meaning.

Comment: @LordCover: but sorting does not actually "use" NP-completeness (in fact it is a problem known to NOT be NP-complete which is what Nick is complaining about above) but rather uses the knowledge that an NP complete algorithm takes a long time to solve. There is no such algorithm called NP-complete. Indeed sorting algorithms are designed to avoid NP-completeness. In other words sorting algorithms try to "not use" NP-completeness. Which in your definition makes sorting no less fundamental than P!=NP.

Comment: @LordCover: if on the other hand you replace the word 'algorithm' with 'problem' or 'knowledge' or 'assumption' in your statement then you would be correct. Which is exactly what I did in my answer.

Comment: @slebetman I'm not doubting you could come up with a sorting algorithm that is NP-complete. But sorting itself is not by any stretch of the imagination NP-complete. There's no link between sorting and NP-completeness except that which you've tried to invent.

Comment: @Nick: I didn't say that sorting is NP-complete. Just that it tends towards being NP-complete. Perhaps I should have rephrased it better and say it tends towards O(n!) instead?

Comment: @slebetman What does "tends towards" even mean in this context? As I said, you can certainly come up with some pretty awful naive sorting algorithms, but that doesn't say anything fundamental about the problem itself.

Comment: @Nick. Yeah, maybe my wording is off. Perhaps the correct terminology is `O(n!)`? Tends towards simply means that there are more ways to write code to be `O(n!)` than not and if you give the problem to a random programmer there is a **tendency** that the resulting code will be `O(n!)`.